# How to perform accumulated avg for multiple companies using spark based on the results stored in Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax, databricks

I need to get avg and count for given dataframe and need to get previously stored avg and count from Cassandra table values for each company.

Then need to calculate avg and count and persist back into the Cassandra table.

How can I do it for each company ?

I have two dataframe schemas as below

```
ingested_df
 |-- company_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- max_dd: date (nullable = true)
 |-- min_dd: date (nullable = true)
 |-- mean: double (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)

cassandra_df 
 |-- company_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- max_dd: date (nullable = true)
 |-- mean: double (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

For each company_id i need to get stored "mean" & "count" 
and calculate "new_mean" & "new_count" and store back in cassandra ...

i.e.

```
    new_mean = ( ingested_df.mean  + cassandra_df.mean) / (ingested_df.count + cassandra_df.count)

   new_count  = (ingested_df.count + cassandra_df.count)
```

How can it be done for each company?

Second Time :

When i tried below join for the same logic above mentioned

```
 val resultDf = cassandra_df.join(ingested_df , 
                            ( cassandra_df("company_id") === ingested_df ("company_id") )
                            ( ingested_df ("min_dd") > cassandra_df("max_dd") )
                        , "left")
```

This is throwing error as below :
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'cassandra_df' is ambiguous, could be: company_id, company_id.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:213)

what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following approach:

```
import spark.implicits._

val ingested_df = Seq(("1", "10", "3")).toDF("company_id", "mean", "count")
val cassandra_df = Seq(("1", "123123", "20", "10")).toDF("company_id", "max_dd", "mean", "count")

val preparedIngestedDf = ingested_df.select("company_id", "mean", "count")

val resultDf = cassandra_df.join(preparedIngestedDf, Seq("company_id"), "left")
  .withColumn("new_mean", (ingested_df("mean") + cassandra_df("mean")) / (ingested_df("count") + cassandra_df("count")))
  .withColumn("new_count", ingested_df("count") + cassandra_df("count"))
  .select(
    col("company_id"),
    col("max_dd"),
    col("new_mean").as("mean"),
    col("new_count").as("new_count")
  )
```

Comment: @dytyniak , Logic wise it is working fine thank you ... But missing one crucial point here ..i.e. if i have multiple company_ids ...and for each company I want to do this how to do it ? how to capture the results ?

Comment: This solution works for multiple companies or I didn’t catch your problem.

Comment: Ohh, do you mean if you have diff companies in cassandra and in new df?

Comment: @dytyniak yes if i have more than one company ?

Comment: Then you should use full_outer join and rewrite logic a little bit.

Comment: @dytyniak added base query block check once... getting error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'cassandra_df' is ambiguous, could be: company_id, company_id.;
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:213)

what is wrong here ?

Comment: @dytyniak tried this but still same ambiguity error ...how to solve it .....  val resultDf = accumulated_results_df.as("a").join(computed_df.as("c"), 
                             ( $"a.company_id" === $"c.company_id" ) && ( $"c.min_dd" > $"a.max_dd" ) , "left")

AnalysisException: Reference 'company_id' is ambiguous, could be: a.company_id, c.company_id.;

Comment: Why are you using different approach to pass join column? That is why you received exception.