# How to solve "aggregateByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset" in Spark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying this example:

https://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-aggregatebykey-example/

But instead of an RDD, I am using a dataframe.

I tried the following:

```
val aggrRDD = student_df.map(r => (r.getString(0), (r.getString(1), r.getInt(2))))
                       .aggregateByKey(zeroVal)(seqOp, combOp)
```

which is a part of a this code snippet :

```
val student_df = sc.parallelize(Array(
    ("Joseph", "Maths", 83), ("Joseph", "Physics", 74), ("Joseph", "Chemistry", 91), ("Joseph", "Biology", 82), 
    ("Jimmy", "Maths", 69), ("Jimmy", "Physics", 62), ("Jimmy", "Chemistry", 97), ("Jimmy", "Biology", 80), 
    ("Tina", "Maths", 78), ("Tina", "Physics", 73), ("Tina", "Chemistry", 68), ("Tina", "Biology", 87), 
    ("Thomas", "Maths", 87), ("Thomas", "Physics", 93), ("Thomas", "Chemistry", 91), ("Thomas", "Biology", 74), 
    ("Cory", "Maths", 56), ("Cory", "Physics", 65), ("Cory", "Chemistry", 71), ("Cory", "Biology", 68), 
    ("Jackeline", "Maths", 86), ("Jackeline", "Physics", 62), ("Jackeline", "Chemistry", 75), ("Jackeline", "Biology", 83), 
    ("Juan", "Maths", 63), ("Juan", "Physics", 69), ("Juan", "Chemistry", 64), ("Juan", "Biology", 60)), 3).toDF("student", "subject", "marks")


def seqOp = (accumulator: Int, element: (String, Int)) => 
    if(accumulator > element._2) accumulator else element._2

def combOp = (accumulator1: Int, accumulator2: Int) => 
    if(accumulator1 > accumulator2) accumulator1 else accumulator2


val zeroVal = 0

val aggrRDD = student_df.map(r => (r.getString(0), (r.getString(1), r.getInt(2))))
                       .aggregateByKey(zeroVal)(seqOp, combOp)
```

That gives this error :

`error: value aggregateByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, (String, Int))]`

A possible cause might be that a semicolon is missing before `value aggregateByKey`?

What am I doing wrong here? How do I work with dataframes or datasets on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call rdd after student_df and before map:

```
val aggrRDD = student_df.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0), (r.getString(1), r.getInt(2))))
          .aggregateByKey(zeroVal)(seqOp, combOp)
```

Comment: thanks a lot , super , it working ... i am confused with this .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620797/value-reducebykey-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rdd

Comment: how to handle this scenario ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473276/how-to-perform-accumulated-avg-for-multiple-companies-using-spark-based-on-the-r

Comment: I can see answer for first link inside and for second I have provided my solution.

Comment: can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037648/how-to-send-each-group-at-a-time-to-the-spark-executors/55038446?noredirect=1#comment96896303_55038446

Comment: var dist_company_model_vals_df =  company_model_vals_df.select("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year").distinct()

// Want to send each group at a time to write by executors.

dist_company_model_vals_df.foreach(rowDf => {
  writeAsParquet(rowDf , parquet_file)    // this simply writes the data as parquet file
})

Comment: You could try to use something like testDf.write.partitionBy("id", "key").parquet("/path/to/file")

Comment: I tried something like this but the problem is it is spilling a lot of Shuffle Input and Output data ...I have 5 nodes with 21 vcores each with  3g Memory ...still it is spilling and more over load is being transferred to single node sometimes.

Comment: Problem could be in your keys. If your data is skewed most of data will be send to the one node.

Comment: Huu there is another issue with skewed data ,...i get data for every quarter since 1980s ... earlier days data being in smaller number ...recent years became bigger   ...not sure how to handle this kind of skew data  where ("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year") are primary keys kind of .. any sample to handle this ...i read "salting" but nowhere i get real solid sample to know how to implement the salting..any advice/help around it

Comment: I could recommend this article for you - https://medium.com/appsflyer/salting-your-spark-to-scale-e6f1c87dd18